# web3.isConnected returns False web3.py

Tags: web3.py, infura, web3-providers

Here is the code I have:

```py
from web3 import Web3

infura_url = 'https://infura.io/project/MyProjectID'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

print(web3.isConnected())
```

The problem is that it returns `False` and I don't know why. Any ideas what I might do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must abide by the [latest url format](https://blog.infura.io/infura-dashboard-transition-update-c670945a922a). Your code should look as follows:

```
from web3 import Web3

infura_url = 'mainnet.infura.io/v3/MyProjectID'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

print(web3.isConnected())
```

Comment: still with infura_url = 'mainnet.infura.io/v3/MyProjectID' it returns false

Comment: Fixed it infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MyProjectID'

Comment: I posted key on edit -_- I deleted and created new obviously